# Queue in generic linked list

Tags: c#, list, generics, queue

I'm new at this and trying to write this code for a queue but it doesn't work. I'm stuck,  I wrote queue for a linked list and I can't find where I'm wrong here, any help is great. Thank you in advance.

```
class Queue
{
    public Node<T> head { get; set; }
    public Node<T> tail { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }

    public Queue()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(value);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.sljedeci = new Node<T>(value);
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        else if (size == 1)
        {
            T value = head.value;
            size--;
            head = tail = null;
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            T value = head.value;
            head = head.next;
            size--;
            return value;
        }
    }

    public void Peek()
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> temp = head;
            Console.Write("{ ");
            while (temp.next != null)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}, ", temp.value);
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            Console.Write(temp.valuet + " }");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a sufficient problem statement. What are you trying to achieve? Are you receiving a compiler error, a runtime exception, or unexpected behaviour and what is the error/exception/unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Check out the generic Queue class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx thsi might do what you want. Unless you are spending your time writing this code for fun :) in that case spend the time debugging your code, you will learn a lot from it.